# How do I write FileContentResult on disk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to use the [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/) component to store (not to show) a copy of the invoice permanently on web server disk. Two questions:

1. Why I need to specify a controller action? ("Index", in this
   case)
2. How do I write the FileContentResult on local disk without
   displaying it?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidationDone(FormCollection formCollection, int orderId, bool fromOrderDetails)
    {
        Order orderValidated = context.Orders.Single(no => no.orderID == orderId);

        CommonUtils.SendInvoiceMail(orderValidated.customerID , orderValidated.orderID);

        var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Temp"), orderValidated.invoiceID + ".pdf");

        var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = orderValidated.invoiceID }) { FileName = filePath };

        var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

        FileContentResult fcr = File(binary, "application/pdf");

        // how do I save 'fcr' on disk?
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need the FileContentResult to create a file. You've got the byte array which can be saved directly to the disk:

```
var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\foobar.pdf", binary);
```

Answer (score 1):

`string FileName="YOUR FILE NAME";`
//first give a name to file

```
string Path=Server.MapPath("YourPath in solution"+Filename+".Pdf")
```

//Give your path and file extention. both are required.

```
binary[]= YOUR DATA
```

//Describe your data to be save as file.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path, binary);
```

**Thats simple...**